# Lazily reading file paragraph by paragraph

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

I've got some data stored in a file where each block of interest is stored in a paragraph like so:

```
hello
there

kind

people
of

stack
overflow
```

I have tried reading each paragraph with the following code, but it does not work:

```
paragraphs = File.open("hundreds_of_gigs").lazy.to_enum.grep(/.*\n\n/) do |p| 
  puts p
end
```

With the regex I am trying to say: "match anything that ends with two newlines"

What am I doing wrong?

Any lazy way of solving this appreciated. The terser the method, the better.

Comment: Non-lazy ways are described here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37696/splitting-a-text-file-into-paragraphs-and-words

Comment: `File#each_line` does exactly what you need

Comment: Erm, I am pretty sure that reads lines and not paragraphs.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat it does, just pass "\n\n" as an argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IO#readline("\n\n")](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-readline) will do what you want. `File` is a subclass of `IO` and has all it's methods even though they are not stated on the File rubydoc page.

It reads line by line, where a line end is the given seperator.

E.g.:

```
f = File.open("your_file")
f.readline("\n\n") => "hello\nthere\n\n"
f.readline("\n\n") => "kind\n\n"
f.readline("\n\n") => "people\nof\n\n"
f.readline("\n\n") => "stack\noverflow\n\n"
```

Each call to readline lazy reads one line of the file starting from top.

Or you can use [IO#each_line("\n\n")](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-each_line) to iterate over the file.

E.g.:

```
File.open("your_file").each_line("\n\n") do |line|
  puts line
end

=> "hello\nthere\n\n"
=> "kind\n\n"
=> "people\nof\n\n"
=> "stack\noverflow\n\n"
```

Comment: That looks like the simplest way to do it. Questions: what if there are more than two "\n"?

Comment: The seperator can basically be anything and you can even change it dynamically. No restrictions there. It reads exactly one line until it finds the seperator or EOF. The next call can even be another seperator. If there are 4 \n  in that example, you would get an empty paragraph.

Comment: For ex-pythonistas: "\n\n" != '\n\n'

Comment: @TheUnfunCat '\n\n' == "\\n\\n"  single quotes treat back slashes as literals

Answer (score 2):

A custom solution. If `IO#readline(sep)` does the work for you, as showed by @ascar, just use it.

```
grouped_lines = open("file.txt").each_line.lazy.map(&:chomp).chunk(&:empty?)
paragraphs = grouped_lines.map { |sep, lines| lines if !sep }.reject(&:nil?)

p paragraphs
#=> <Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator::Lazy:... 

p paragraphs.to_a
#=> [["hello", "there"], ["kind"], ["people", "of"], ["stack", "overflow"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lazy method that works when paragraphs are separated by one or more empty lines. I don't believe the other solutions permit variable spacing between paragraphs.

**Code**

```
def paragraphs(fname)
  complete = true
  IO.foreach(fname).with_object([]) do |l,a|
    if l.size > 1
      if complete
        a << l
        complete = false
      else
        a[-1] << l
      end
    else
      complete = true
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "hello\nthere\n\nkind\n\n\npeople\nof\n\n\n\n\nstack\noverflow"
fname = 'tmp'
File.write(fname, str)

paragraphs(fname)
  #=> ["hello\nthere\n", "kind\n", "people\nof\n", "stack\noverflow"]
```